# Why does go give me this result?

Tags: go, floating-point

I am making a program that calculates the percentage of males and females in the class. But it gives me an incorrect result.

The code is:

```golang
package main
import {
    "fmt"
}

var total, mujeres, hombres float64

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Número de mujeres:")
    fmt.Scanln(&mujeres)

    fmt.Printf("Número de hombres:")
    fmt.Scanln(&hombres)

    total = mujeres + hombres
    mujeres = (mujeres / total) * 100
    hombres = (hombres / total) * 100

    print("En al salón de clases hay ", mujeres, "% de mujeres y ", 
        hombres, "% de hombres")
}
```

And the output I'm getting when entering `50` for both quantities is:

```
En al salón de clases hay +5.000000+001% de mujeres y +5.000000+001% de hombres
```

I want to know what causes this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Jean Carlo, please ensure in future that code is entered in the question as text rather than as an image (whether in the question or external to the question). Images make it very hard for people to help you out, so are likely to be closed as not suitable. I've converted your image to code/output for this question though, admittedly, simplified it a little because my Spanish(?) is rather limited. As in "hombres" from old Western movies, and "y" from the fast food chain Guzman y Gomez, which is Mexican but close :-)

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not giving an incorrect result, it's giving the *correct* result in an incorrect format. The *value* `+5.000000e+001` is `5x101`, which is equal to `50`.

If you want them formatted differently to the default, you need to specify that, such as with:

```golang
fmt.Printf("En al salón de clases hay %.1f%% du mujeres y %.1f%% du hombres\n",
    mujeres, hombres)
```